# SQL Server 2005 extension on Linux

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux, webserver

Does anyone know how I can install an Ms SQL extension 2005 on a Linux webserver?
The webserver currently has FreeTDS library version, I have no idea on what that means. But when I try to connect it doesn't say "mssql_connect() does not exist" But it says "Unable to connect to server: xx.xx.xx.xx"

I am supposing that this is because of the version of the extension since I have occured this problem on windows with ntwdblib.dll. But I don't know how to fix this on Linux.

I only need to use the functions. The database is on a windows server so I want to connect to it using mssql_connect().

Comment: This won't help answer your question, but why not develop on a Windows machine? The closer your development environment resembles your production environment, the fewer headaches you'll have.

Comment: Did you compile in the MS SQL support in PHP?

Comment: @Matt maybe their production is environment is setup like these: Web Server: Linux, Database Server: SQL Server. So there, his development environment resembles the production environment ;-)

Comment: Well the thing is, the linux server is a webhost company. But I happen to know them and they are trying to get mssql extension version 2005 to work for me but well they don't have mssql experience and I never worked with linux so yea.. I checked phpinfo and mssql is on its just not the right version I think. We don't know what to change for that. Like I said on windows its just the ntwbdlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `mssql_*` functions on Linux using the FreeTDS library, but support needs to be compiled into the PHP binary (`--with-mssql`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the unixODBC module?  **sudo apt-get install unixodbc**

Have you installed ODBC support for PHP?  **sudo apt-get install php5-odbc**

Have you defined the connection to the Microsoft Sequel Server in your odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files?

```
odbc.ini

# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
# The Description can be whatever we want it to be.
# The Driver value must match what we have defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini
# The Database name must be the name of the database this connection will connect to.
# The ServerName is the name we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# The TDS_Version should match what we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[msft_sql_server]
Description             = The Microsoft Sequel Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = XXXXXXXXXX
ServerName              = msft_sql_server
TDS_Version             = 8.0

odbcinst.ini

# Define where to find the driver for the Free TDS connections.
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

And then your PHP connection will look something like this:

```
$db_connection = new PDO("dblib:dbname=$database_server;host=$database_server", $db_username, $db_password);
```

You can test the above set up using the iSQL program just to make sure you can establish a connection.

If you're still having trouble connecting from your Linux server to the MSFT server - is there a firewall in the way?  Are you sure you have valid user credentials?  Will the MSFT server accept connections from a remote client?